# Integral of $\frac{2}{(x^2+2x+5)^{1/2}}$

Tags: integration

Please, I am stuck here for hours. Can somebody help me find the following integral $$\frac{2}{(x^2+2x+5)^{1/2}}$$ Only thing I can do is turn this into $$\frac{2}{(x^2+2x+1+4)^{1/2}} = \frac{2}{((x+1)^2+2^2)^{1/2}}$$ Don't know if that helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}=\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}=2\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2+4}$$

and use 
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\sinh^{-1}x+C$$
with the change variable $$t=\frac{x+1}{2}$$

Comment: Should that say $\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}$?

Comment: @ZettaSuro Yes thank you.

Comment: Alright, we have not been taught hyperbolic sine yet. Don't know why this is part of my homework. Thanks a lot though :)

Comment: @darkchampionz $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}$.

Comment: @darkchampionz we have $\sinh^{-1}(x)=\log(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:
For $\sqrt{(x+a)^2+b^2}$ use $x+a=b\tan\theta$

For $\sqrt{(x+a)^2-b^2}$ use $x+a=b\sec\theta$

For $\sqrt{b^2-(x+a)^2}$ use $x+a=b\sin\theta$